# Create website background image that changes on a click

Tags: jquery, html, background

I am wondering how to create a background image that will change when clicked. It's supposed to go through a sequence of images like this. Any clues how to make this?

Comment: could you please relink your example? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The jQuery Way

Here's a basic jQuery solution:

```
var images = [
  'http://placekitten.com/500/500',
  'http://placekitten.com/400/400',
  'http://placekitten.com/750/750'
];

$(".changeBG").on("click", function(){
  $("body").css("backgroundImage", function( o, v ) {
    var backg = v.match( /\((.+)\)/ );
    var index = $.inArray( ( backg ? backg[1] : "" ), images );
    return "url('" + ( images[++index] || images[0] ) + "')";
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/isubag/2/edit

#### The Pure JavaScript (almost) Way

That solution is pretty heavy on the jQuery, which will slow it down just a bit. You could go with a far more holistic approach. Unfortunately there is still the use of `$.inArray` (though [polyfills do exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)), as native support for `indexOf` on arrays isn't all that great.

```
var bg = {
  images: [
    'http://placekitten.com/500/500',
    'http://placekitten.com/400/400',
    'http://placekitten.com/750/750'
  ],
  get: function () {
    var match = document.body.style.backgroundImage.match( /\((.+)\)/ );
    return match ? match[1] : "" ;
  },
  set: function ( url ) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')" ; 
  }
};

function bgCycler () {
  var index = $.inArray( bg.get(), bg.images );
  bg.set( bg.images[++index] || bg.images[0] );
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/isubag/edit#javascript,html