# change background image with scroll

Tags: jquery, image, background, scroll

I have a bunch of images that are supposed to fit the entire browser and when you scroll, it would change to the next picture and so on. I'm new to this and I really have no idea what I'm doing. I've been looking at this: [Create website background image that changes on a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544270/create-website-background-image-that-changes-on-a-click) which is basically what I want, but instead of changing on a click, it would be changing on a scroll.

Don't know if it's the same concept... any ideas?

Comment: You should really add more information to questions this vague.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **$(window).scrollTop()** to determine current scroll amount and **$(body).css('background-image', '/i/image.jpg')** to actually change the background image.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var image_url = '/i/image1.jpg'
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        image_url = '/i/image2.jpg';
    }
    $(body).css('background-image', "url('" + image_url + "')");
});
```

This is just a conception. You should place all your images inside an "array" (like in your example) and determine image to apply dynamically.

Comment: I found you need to add the 'url()' part when changing the background. $("body").css('background-image', 'url("'+image_url)+'")';

Comment: Your are right, I've updated the answer. Thanks.