# change colour of header when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm going to cut to the chase straight away, basically I want my header to go from transparent (no background attribute in the css) to having a `background-color` of white on scroll.

I am using this JavaScript and not getting anywhere.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var changeNav = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36)'
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        changeNav = '#ffffff';
    }
    $(.header).css('background-color', changeNav);
});
```

Also, is there a way I can make it go back on itself? So I am at the bottom of the page and the header has a `background-color` of white, but when I scoll to the top, JavaScript takes the attribute out? I have been playing about and searching but couldn't find anything.

**NOTE:** I had gotten this piece of JavaScript from another place on Stack Overflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996491/change-background-image-with-scroll)

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you have jquery linked?

Comment: That code *is* JavaScript, or better a JavaScript library called [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), so you need to include/call that library in order to use it. See my demo for an example on jsBin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change header background colour when page scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266651/change-header-background-colour-when-page-scrolls)

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/teriha/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

`$(.header)` should be `$(".header")`

also your script can be "simplified" to:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop() > 200;
    $(".header").css('background-color', scrolled ? '#fff' : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36)");
});
```

**Note** that the above will *force* `.header` background color change (even from #fff to #fff) on every scroll. To **leverage that** and to make sure that you have the right colors even if the user **resizes the window** use:

```
$( function () { // DOM ready to be manipulated

   var $header = $(".header"); // Cache elements for intensive actions
   $(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
       if($(this).scrollTop() > 200){
           $header.css('background-color', "#fff" );
       }else{
           $header.css('background-color', "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36)" );
       }
   });

});
```

Ofc, make sue you've included the jQuery library inside the `<head>` of your document:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```